# How to jack cars from the passenger seat?

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-online

I've seen videos of people driving around in cars, and then the player in the passenger seat pushes the driver out of the car and takes control of it. Pressing `F` just makes you jump out of the car and I have been unable to find any controls in the manual or elsewhere. If anyone knows the control for this (PC) that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

- On playstation, you hold down **`triangle`**
- On Xbox, hold down **`Y`**
- On PC, since **`triangle`** and **`Y`** mean that you hold down the "Enter vehicle" button, you hold **`F`**.

Comment: I did this and I just jumped out of the car.

Comment: @Crubleigh stand beside passenger door, press and hold the keys Rizky has told, you should get control of the vehicle. If you hold those keys while in drivers seat, you'll definitely jump out of the car